# Ballerina: cannot find package when pushing a package

Tags: package, ballerina

When pushing a package, uploads the package to Ballerina Central. Using the push command.

```
ballerina push <package-name>
```

It gives an error showing

```
Compiling source    
ballerina: cannot find package <package-name>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow these steps when you push a package to Ballerina Central.

1. Initialize your package - `ballerina init`
2. Build your package - `ballerina build <package-name>`
3. Push your package - `ballerina push <package-name>`

---

Please refer guide [1] for more details on how to create a project and guide [2] for a complete guide on how to create client endpoint.

[1] https://ballerina.io/learn/how-to-structure-ballerina-code/#projects

[2] https://medium.com/ldclakmal/how-to-write-a-client-endpoint-in-ballerina-3c24c185ffaf